# What is "AWS_LOG_STREAM" in amazon-CloudWatch?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

```
cloudwatch.CloudwatchHandler('AWS_KEY_ID','AWS_SECRET_KEY','AWS_REGION','AWS_LOG_GROUP','AWS_LOG_STREAM')
```

I am new to AWS cloudwatch and I am trying to use cloudwatch lightweight handler in my python project. I have all the values required for `.CloudwatchHandler()` except `AWS_LOG_STREAM`. I am not understanding what is `AWS_LOG_STREAM` where I can i find that value in the AWS console. I googled "A log stream is a sequence of log events that share the same source." but does it mean "same source". And what is the value for `AWS_LOG_STREAM`?
I need support and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As Mohit said, the log stream is a subdivision of the log group, usually to identify the original execution source (time and ID of the container, lambda or process is common)

In the latest version you can skip naming the log stream which will give it a timestamp log stream name:

```py
handler = cloudwatch.CloudwatchHandler(log_group = 'my_log_group')
```

*Disclaimer: I am a contributor to the cloudwatch package*

Answer (score 0):

AWS_LOG_STREAM is basically log group events divided based on execution time. by specifying a stream you're getting logs for a specific time duration rather than since inception.

example: incase of AWS Lambda, you can check it's current log stream by

`LOG_GROUP=log-group`

`aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name $LOG_GROUP --log-stream-name aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name $LOG_GROUP --max-items 1 --order-by LastEventTime --descending --query logStreams[].logStreamName --output text | head -n 1 --query events[].message --output text`

else in python, you can use boto3 to fetch existing log streams and then call cloudwatch handler with the respective stream name

[https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.describe_log_streams]